# jquery not sending the value to another input value in modal popup

Tags: php, jquery

I am having a task that the form contains different inputs. Before going to save the data the user has to go for preview. Preview is loading in a modal popup which contains some inputs. In the inputs presented in modal popup is loaded with the values entered by the user in the form. i have written some code. but when i click on preview it was not loading in modal popup. can anybody help. my code goes here

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function(){
    
               $('#preview').click(function(){
                   var f_name=$('#name').val();         
                   $('#name1').val(f_name);
            });         
          });   
   </script>
   
   <div class="modal-body">               
     1. Name of the Applicant <input type="text" name="name1" id="name1" required />                   
   </div> 
   
Name of the Applicant                  
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" maxlength="50" required />
<button id="preview" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Preview</button>
```

Comment: How does your modal gets called ? where is `#preview` element ?

Comment: sorry i missed  it. Now its working fine.